# Isn't git add an extra command?

Tags: git, github, command-line, gitlab

Isn't `git add` an extra command. Everything `git add` does can also be achieved by `git commit` if add command is removed. Just want to know others thought on it.

Comment: Huh? No. You are probably coming from another version control system which doesn't have a separate staging state.

Comment: If *F* is an untracked file, "git commit *F*" produces an error message, but "git add *F*" adds `F` to the proposed next commit. So, no.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same.

`git add` adds the modified files to the queue to be committed later so the files are not yet committed.

`git commit` on the other hand does commits the files that have been added and creates a new revision with a log (so in case you didn't add any files, git will not commit anything)

Note, that you can combine both commands with providing the `-a` flag at the end of the git commit like so:
`git commit -a`

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the fact that `git commit --include <files>` is roughly equivalent to running `git add` on the list of files, then `git commit`. Using `git commit -a` is roughly equivalent to running `git add -u`, then `git commit`. Note that these use an extra index, which creates interesting effects with poorly written pre-commit hooks; `git commit --only <files>` uses *two* extra index files, which creates even more problems.

Comment: Yes, I was just saying git should probably simplify the process of a push by managing both `git add` and `git commit` in a single command, which you all have mentioned can be done by `git commit -a`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can, in many cases, use built-in features of `git commit` to add files to be committed at the same time you're committing, so that you don't need to use `git add`.

However, doing so deprives you of the opportunity to look at the staged and unstaged changes and verify you've collected the expected contents.  For example, this past week, I wrote about four commits' worth of changes and then staged independent pieces of them with `git add -p` before committing, verifying at each step that I had included only the intended pieces.  I *could* have done this with `git commit -p`, but I probably would have made a mistake.

For more advanced users, it tends to be a lot less common to use `git commit` with specific files and more common to stage changes with `git add` before committing.